# Remove stopwords from Literary Text File when creating collocates list for a specific word

Tags: python-3.x

https://github.com/sgsinclair/alta/blob/2acb6ed09f298f631e4025d33f062f980758a1ce/ipynb/utilities/Collocates.ipynb

Hello, I am completely new to python and programming.  I am following the tutorial at the above link in order to find collocations of a specific word in a text file.  I was wondering if there is a way to remove stop words from the entire text file before creating a list of collocations in the following script?

I have tried the following code but it isn't working:

```
 %ls *.txt

 targetText = "Hume Treatise.txt"

  with open(targetText, "r") as f:
    theText = f.read()

  print("This string has", "{:,}".format(len(theText)), "characters")

  import re
  theTokens = re.findall(r'\b\w[\w-]*\b', theText.lower())
  print(theTokens[:10])


  wrd2find = input("What word do you want collocates for?") 
  context = 5

  end = len(theTokens)
  counter = 0
  theCollocates = []
  for word in theTokens:
    if word == wrd2find:
       for i in range(context):
          if (counter - (i + 1)) >= 0: 
              theCollocates.append(theTokens[(counter - (i + 1))]) 
          if (counter + (i + 1)) < end: 
              theCollocates.append(theTokens[(counter + (i + 1))]) 
          counter = counter + 1

          print(theCollocates[:10])

          import nltk
          tokenDist = nltk.FreqDist(theCollocates)
          tokenDist.tabulate(10)

          from nltk.corpus import stopwords
          filtered_words = [word for word in word_list if word not in              
          stopwords.words('english')]


          import matplotlib
          %matplotlib inline
          tokenDist.plot(25, title="Top Frequency Collocates for " +         
          wrd2find.capitalize())
```